# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) cant get firebase data FLUTTER,DART

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#6d86e):
Null check operator used on a null value

the problem is in Map<String, dynamic> user = snap.data!.data()!;
//_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) FLUTTER

```
class ProfileView extends GetView<ProfileController> {
  const ProfileView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Profile'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: controller.streamUser(),
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snap.hasData) {
            Map<String, dynamic> user = snap.data!.data()!;
            return ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50,
                ),
                Text("$user"),
                Text("Nama"),
                Text("Email"),
                Text("Last Login"),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Tidak dapat memuat data user"),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

idont know what the main problem is it, already running flutter doctor seems doesnt help

Comment: `snap.hasData` can be true if the streamed document is not found. Check `snap.data!.data() == null`, if it is true, the query in `streamUser` have not found the document.